# Expand a view controller's view to fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a fairly complex view controller hierarchy in my app. I currently have a view, which I want to make full screen with a button tap. The problem is, because this view is inside a view controller's view that only takes a proportion of the screen, I'm unable to simply set the frame to the size of the application window. I also cannot present the view modally, as this would interfere with the rest of my UI.

To help explain what I mean:

```
UIViewController // root view controller
    --> UIViewController
         --> UIViewController
         --> UIViewController
    --> UIViewController
         --> Controller's View <----- // this one
    --> UIViewController
```

I need to make the view shown above, that as already being displayed inside a view controller to expand into full screen.

Any idea's of the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing some similar stuff hope this help. I have video player that support full screen video.

Please see this code, you will need to do changes as this is just some part of my code with some changes just to show how i did it..

```
UIView *rootView =  [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] view];
CGRect rect = [myView convertRect: myView.frame toView:rootView];
UIView *interactionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
interactionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[interactionView.layer insertSublayer:myView.layer below:otherView.layer ];// i am using otherView u can use if any or use addSublayer otherwise
myView.layer.frame = rootView.bounds;
interactionView.frame = rootView.bounds;
```

Comment: Thanks @wuiii. I had to make a number of changes to get it working how I wanted, that was a great starting point.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIView *yourview = yourViewController.view; 

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
    yourview.frame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks Nikos for the quick response, but this doesn't work. Reason being, the frame is resized to the application's window, and in theory that would work, but since the view is currently displayed in a view that is taking (let's say half the iPad screen), the view is resized ... but it starts at {0,0} of the parent view. Which if you translate it to the iPad screen, may be {524,0}.